# How do I get Siri to create a note?

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit

I am trying to use SiriKit to create a note. Here is my code in the Intents App Extension:

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension {
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        
        print("IntentHandler.handler(_:)")
        
        guard let createNoteIntent = intent as? INCreateNoteIntent else {
            
            return self
            
        }
        
        if let textNoteContent = createNoteIntent.content as? INTextNoteContent {
            
            print(textNoteContent.text as Any)
            
        }
        
        return CreateEntry()
        
    }
    
}

import UIKit
import Intents

class CreateEntry: NSObject, INCreateNoteIntentHandling {
    
    func handle(intent: INCreateNoteIntent, completion: @escaping (INCreateNoteIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        
        print("CreateEntry.handle(_:_:)")
        
        if let textNoteContent = intent.content as? INTextNoteContent {
            
            print(textNoteContent.text as Any)
            
        }
        
        let note = INNote(title: INSpeakableString(spokenPhrase: "May the force be with you."), contents: [INNoteContent()], groupName: nil, createdDateComponents: nil, modifiedDateComponents: nil, identifier: nil)
        
        let response = INCreateNoteIntentResponse(code: INCreateNoteIntentResponseCode.ready, userActivity: nil)
        
        response.createdNote = note
        
        completion(response)
        
    }
    
}
```

When I ask Siri "Create note using Journal", Siri responds with "Sorry, there was a problem with the app." and my code prints these results.

> IntentHandler.handler(_:)
>
> IntentHandler.handler(_:)
>
> IntentHandler.handler(_:)
>
> IntentHandler.handler(_:)
>
> IntentHandler.handler(_:)
>
> CreateEntry.handle(*:*:)

When I change the INCreateNoteIntentResponseCode argument of INCreateNoteIntentResponse to success, Siri responds by saying the note was created and then shows me what the note says, "May the force be with you."

Siri never asked what to say in the note. I thought if I sent a response of ready like in my code above, that Siri would ask the user what to write in the note.

I'm stumped here. There is a lack of documentation for this.

Comment: @MehulThakkar No. It may be it won't work until I get permission from Apple to access notes in Contacts. For security reasons Apple requires that we make a request to them in order to allow our apps to access notes.

Comment: After many trials and errors, I am able to create notes via siri now. JFYI: That note is not going to be added to system's notes app, its for our custom app.

Answer (score 0):

There are optional methods in the Intent Handler that need to be implemented. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/increatenoteintenthandling for details.

- The parameters that are passed should be validated in the `resolve*` methods. The first parameter `INCreateNoteIntent` has title, content and groupName fields. Depending on whether a parameter is required or optional for your application, you can call the `completion` callback with the appropriate response. This is partial validation.
- `confirm` is called when all the parameters are set and final validation needs to be done. This is where you can send the `.ready` status code.
- `handle` is called when the intent needs to be executed, in this intent actual creation of the INNote. Like the other calls, the actual parameters spoken by the user are present in the first parameter.